# ASP.NET - Is it possible to put the user agent into an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-agent

I have seen the user agent and yes it holds a nice set of information but in an ugly string and not in a lovely object where I can reference certain parts.

Is there an object that holds the user agent or a way I can take this ugly string and turn it into a lovely object?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [HttpRequest.Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Try and add the 51Degrees.mobi NUget package: https://nuget.org/packages/51Degrees.mobi - it is designed for mobile detection, but it might have enriched browser capabilities you can use.

Answer (score 0):

The User-Agent string format is currently specified by Section 14.43 of [RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.43)

> The field can contain multiple product tokens (section 3.8) and
> comments identifying the agent and any subproducts which form a
> significant part of the user agent

```
User-Agent     = "User-Agent" ":" 1*( product | comment )
```

Therefore it would be very hard to create a specific object which would be able to parse the UA string and store the values, you could possibly create a list of Key Value pairs for the info in the UA string.